# Git: Accidentally used git branch -f instead of git checkout -f - how can I restore the branch?

Tags: git

While on a branch (`test`) I accidentally hit `git branch master -f` in an attempt to switch to the master branch... seconds later I saw my error and checked out `master` branch with `git checkout master -f`, and saw that the previous command seemed to have completely replaced the `master` branch with the `test` branch.

How can I reset `master` to it's previous state?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `git reflog`. It should still show the lost commits on the master branch. Take the most recent one (denoted `XXXXXXX` below) and make it the master's head:

```
$ git reflog
a092834 HEAD@{0}: commit: changes on test
b6affd1 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to test
XXXXXXX HEAD@{2}: commit: last commit to master
```

You can switch to a lost commit by `checkout`, the same way as normally. Then recreate the master there the same way you lost it:

```
git checkout XXXXXXX
git branch master -f  # Your command again!
git checkout master
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thank you very much choroba.